# Styling a list item with a child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been going around in circles for hours, I keep getting errors with this code :

```
$('div.colA div.region-sidebar-left div.menu-block-wrapper').find('li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('> ul').size() > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('has_child');
        }
});
```

All it is supposed to do is find all the `<li>` with a child of `<ul>` and give it a class. Simple.

http://jsfiddle.net/simcox90/mEMmN/

Comment: there is no html to go with that fiddle.

Comment: What is the problem? what do you want to happen? this is no way to ask  a question.

Comment: Please check you fiddle before giving a link.

Comment: @Aron Rotteveel plesae update you fiddle or use this fork I made: http://jsfiddle.net/NQuGk/1/

Comment: The intent is clear with the code and "All it does" which describes the goal.

Comment: Changed it to the clearer "all it is supposed to do" :)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
$(this).find('> ul').size();
```

You can say:

```
$(this).children("ul").length
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/children/

---

And I think you can use this oneliner instead:

```
$('div.colA div.region-sidebar-left div.menu-block-wrapper li > ul').parent().addClass("has_child");
```

`$('li > ul').parent()` returns all `li` nodes witch has a `ul` as a child.